# Return the file name of the list item

Tags: python, arrays, list, opencv, matrix

I have a *list* called `pairs`: `pairs = []`

Each item in the `pairs` list is a pair of images:

```
pair = (im1,im2)
pairs.append(pair)
```

`im1` and `im2` are simply image files on the hard disk:

```
im1 = cv2.imread('im1.jpg')
im2 = cv2.imread('im2.jpg')
```

When I print the items in the `pairs` list, I get a matrix representing the elements (images). How can I return the image file names (`im1.jpg` and `im2.jpg`) instead?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might need to use a dictionary or another list and store the name of the file

Comment: you’re not storing the strings, so you could create another tuple `img=(im1, ‘img1.png)` and store pairs of these tuples, then do img[1] to get the file name

Comment: You can't, the `im1` variable stores *only* the image as an array. You need to store the image along with the filename. So for e.g. you could do `im1_file = 'im1.jpg'` and `im1 = cv2.imread(im1_file)`, and then store the list of images as a dictionary, or a list of pairs, etc. E.g. `{im1_file: im1, ...}` or `[(im1_file, im1), ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the filename from the array. The variable `im1 = cv2.imread(...)` *only* stores the array values. It is stored as a standard numpy `ndarray` object and there is no attribute referencing the filenames.

However, there are a lot of options here to do what you want, some that are very typical patterns for Python. Generally, you're looking to store two pieces of information: the filename and the image array. One option is just to have two lists, one being the filenames and the other the images:

```
>>> filename_list = ['im1.jpg', 'im2.jpg', ...]
>>> im_list = [cv2.imread(filename) for filename in filename_list]
```

Another way is to store these as pairs:

```
>>> filename1 = 'im1.jpg'
>>> filename2 = 'im2.jpg'
>>> im1 = cv2.imread(filename1)
>>> im2 = cv2.imread(filename2)
>>> im_pairs = [(filename1, im1), (filename2, im2), ...]
```

or if you already have the filenames and images as lists (as in the first case) you can use a list comprehension to build the pairs:

```
>>> im_pairs = [(filename, im) for filename, im in zip(filename_list, im_list)]
```

A better option (in terms of code reuse in actual projects) with the same idea as above is to create a `namedtuple` so it's more explicit what each item is:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Img = namedtuple('Img', ['name', 'data'])
>>> im1 = Img('im1.jpg', np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
>>> im1.name
'im1.jpg'
>>> im1.data
array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

And here you can just create a list of `Img` objects.

A fourth option is to use a Python dictionary with the key being the name and the value being the arrays:

```
>>> filename1 = 'im1.jpg'
>>> filename2 = 'im2.jpg'
>>> im1 = cv2.imread(filename1)
>>> im2 = cv2.imread(filename2)
>>> im_pairs = {filename1: im1, filename2: im2, ...}
```

or again with a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> im_pairs = {filename: im for filename, im in zip(filename_list, im_list)}
```

All of these methods are pretty standard so it's up to you how you'd want to use them. There are tons of other ways too, but I think the above are the most common.

Answer (score 0):

The `imread()` function of the opencv library returns a numpy array. So you can't really access the file name from this. I would try something like this:

```
class Image(object):
    def __init__(self, image_name):
        self.image_name = cv2.imread(image_name)
        self.name = image_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Create your images:

```
im1 = Image('im1.jpg')
im2 = Image('im2.jpg')
```

Append the `(im1, im2)` pair to your `pairs` list. Then, when you print the the items in the pairs list just make sure to print their `__str__` representation:

```
for p in pairs:
    print (str(p[0]), str(p[1]))
```

Comment: If you define both a `__str__()` and a `__repr__()` on your class you won't need to explicitly cast as a string.